# Excel Macro to delete if more than 10 words

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of text values, and I was wondering how I can remove cells that have more than 10 words. Is there some way I can count the SPACE characters, and delete the cell if there is more than 9?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you got a text string in, say, cell `A1`, you can then determine how many space characters there is in that cell by using this formula in, say, cell `B1`:

```
=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))
```

Comment: Nice idea, I suppose I can wrap this in a script...

Answer (score 0):

sure, this is to remove all cells that are bigger than 10 words in column A, for row 1 to 100.

```
sub test()
for r = 1 to 100
    space_count = 0
    for c = 1 to len(range("A" & r)) 
       if mid(range("A" & r),c,1) = " " then space_count = space_count + 1
       if space_count > 8 then range("A" & r).clearcontents
    Next
Next
end sub
```

Comment: Nice Macro but I'm after words not characters.

Comment: yes I realized after :)